# I want to automatically increase table row after clicking button

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

[image: *****]

Hi, my problem is increasing the table row automatically. Actually, when I click GET button the product type and product name values are getting from database. Here, after getting those values, I will give another id based on that id again for values will come. But it was not setting in another row. Here is my `java` code and `jsp`:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

System.out.println("driver loaded");
System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charms?user=root&password=root");
System.out.println("Connection created");
Statement st =con.createStatement();
String query="select * from product where ProductType_v='"+a+"' and ProductId_v='"+b+"'";
ResultSet rs = (ResultSet)st.executeQuery(query);
int i=0;
    while(rs.next())
    {
        i++;
        request.getSession().setAttribute("edit","success");
        request.getSession().setAttribute("proType ", rs.getString("ProductType_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("proId", rs.getString("ProductId_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("strength", rs.getString("Strength_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("proName", rs.getString("ProductName_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("brand", rs.getString("BrandName_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("generic", rs.getString("GenricName_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("uom", rs.getString("UOM_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("formE", rs.getString("FormE_v"));
        request.getSession().setAttribute("presReqd", rs.getString("PresReqd_v"));
    }
    if(i==0)
    {
        request.getSession().setAttribute("edit", "fail");
    }
}
catch(Exception e)


jsp code

<tr>  
    <td>
        <input class="textfield-form-date-req" type="text" id="pro_type">
    </td>
    <%
        if(editStatus =="success")
        {
    %>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("pro_type").value='<%=session.getAttribute("proType")%>';
    </script>
    <%
    }
    <td>
        <input class="textfield-form-date-req" type="text" id="pro_id">
    </td>
    <% 
        if(editStatus =="success")
        {
    %>
    <scripttype="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById("pro_id").value='<%=session.getAttribute("proName")%>';
    </script>
    <% 
    }
    %>                  
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td> 
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: helloooooooooooooo is there any1

Comment: I am here to help.What you want ?

Comment: thank u any suggestion for my problem

Comment: Normally if you want to do such functionality , you have to go with ajax.

Comment: @Human being i don't know ajax

Comment: If you click the button , you have to append the data from the data base in to the table. Is that your requirement ?

Comment: no i done that already.my requirement i will give id no based on that id no the data stored in the database will come to my table.if i give another id those values are coming in the same row.first row are not coming. i want first row values and second row values also.in two different rows

Comment: requrement is confusing.

Comment: my requirement is table row should increase automatically when ever i retrieve data from database.i want previous data and also present data in the table

Comment: NO problem.I will help

Comment: @Human Being where r u bro!?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49555/discussion-between-human-being-and-saideep)

Comment: Let me know the status .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a sample for you with `ajax`. It gets the data from the `server side` and append it , in the existing table.

The jar files I have used is ,

1. **jackson-all-1.9.0.jar** - to convert the java object to json format
2. **servlet-api-2.4.jar** - for servlet

My `TableAppend.jsp` will be,

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script
    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {

            //alert("DOM is ready");

        });

        function sendData() {

            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : "TableAppend",
                data : "name=" + $('#name').val() + "&age=" + $('#age').val()
                        + "&sid=" + new Date(),
                dataType : 'html',
                success : function(result) {
                    //alert("Result ::::>>> "+result);
                    if(result != null && $.trim(result) != "" && result != undefined){
                        var json = JSON.parse(result);
                        //alert(json.name);
                        //alert(json.age);
                        appendToTable(json.name, json.age);
                    }

                },
                error : function(e) {
                    alert('Error in Processing');
                }

            });
        }

        function appendToTable(name, age) {
            var tr = "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + age + "</td></tr>"
            $('#mytable').append(tr);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Name :
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" /> Age :
    <input type="text" id="age" name="age" />

    <input type="button" value="Append to table" onclick="sendData()">
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <br></br>
    <table id="mytable" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Age</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>HumanBeing</td>
                <td>25</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Saideep</td>
                <td>26</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```

My `TableAppend.java servlet` will be,

```
public class TableAppend extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * Default constructor. 
     */
    public TableAppend() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setContentType("UTF");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String age = request.getParameter("age");
        String json ="";
        System.out.println("-----------------");
        if(name != null && age != null){
            TableAppendPojo obj = new TableAppendPojo();
            obj.setName(name);
            obj.setAge(age);

            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
            System.out.println("json : "+json);
        }
        out.println(json);
    }

}
```

Then `java class` will be,

```
public class TableAppendPojo {

    private String name;
    private String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }


}
```

**Note :** Please apply the above logic in your code . In your case , you don't need to give the data from the `UI`. You retrieves the data from the `database` in the `servlet`.So please convert the retrieved data from the `database` to the `json` format and append it to the `table`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please apply the above logic in your code . In your case no need to give the data from the UI. It comes from the data base to the servlet.

Comment: Anyway , Finally you got the solution. Happy to hear.